# Trim Video Functionality in an android App

Tags: android, ffmpeg, trim

I want Trim Video Functionality in an android App. I have gone through different post and references but did not found any suitable solution. Can you please tell me any open source repository link? I would prefer FFMPEG Lib for trim video.

The only source I found is: https://github.com/uday-rayala/video-trimmer, However it doesn't show video thumbnails like Vine/Instagram/vivavideo etc.

I want to show video thumbnails while trimming video, as shown in below screen shot.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look over here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-media-pack-for-android-tutorials-running-samples

It has a sample of cutting a video which you can use in your application by downloading and including their Starter Edition pack. It's completely free but you'd have to register through and can be used in Android Studio, Eclipse and many other IDEs.

Open source example codes that includes the java files to trim/cut your video into segments. You can even compress the videos which can be done by standard Android SDK as well.

https://github.com/INDExOS/media-for-mobile/tree/master/Android/samples/apps/src/com/intel/inde/mp/samples

Comment: thanks. I have looked into this. I would prefer FFMPEG solution

Comment: @NaeemShah Hi, did you found a solution for your problem? Thanks.

Comment: I have used the above solution however its not good solution, having some limitation like: it works for android version above 4.3 and second video trim only works for H.264 video codec.